# Is my query string redirect right?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

I want to redirect mypage.com/store/index.php?product_id=62&thisvar=doesntmatter to mypage.com/store#page-anchor. My current redirect looks like this, but doesn't seem to be doing anything. Am I doing something wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*product_id=62(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/store/index\.php$ /store#page-anchor [R=301,L]
```

Edit: I should note that I have the following lines before my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `([^&]&)*` bit doesn't look quite right. It matches strings like "a&b&c&" (a pair of a non-& character and a &, repeated any number of times), and that's probably not what you want. I guess you wanted to write `([^&]*&)*`, but I'd suggest `(^|&)product_id=62(&|$)` (for safety, readability and elegance).

Oh and, if it's in your .htaccess (and not your httpd.conf), the pattern in the RewriteRule should be a relative URI, i.e. it shouldn't start with a `/`.

Comment: Great, I made both of those changes and it is now redirecting. It seems that the # is causing troubles now though. The resulting URL is mypage.com/store%23page-anchor. Escaping the # using a \ (i.e. \#) doesn't seem to make a difference. What is the proper way to deal with this?

Comment: It looks like the [NE] (no escape) flag is what was needed. The final working redirect looks like this
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)product_id=62(&|$)`
 
`RewriteRule ^store/index\.php$ store\#page-anchor? [R=301,NE,L]`